Mocha fails to use typescript baseUrl setting for ESM imports
I'm trying to get "absolute" import paths working in our mocha test files. These work fine for our Vite/TS React app.
import { agent } from 'tests/shared/supertest'
I've tried adding ts-node/tsconfig-paths to the config per their recommendation, but it still errors with Cannot find package 'tests' imported from tests\configs\mocha\setup.ts
I tried using ts-mocha too but for people using ESM like we are, it's not working either: https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha/issues/74
.mocharc.json:
{
  "extensions": ["ts"],
  "node-option": ["experimental-specifier-resolution=node", "loader=ts-node/esm", "no-warnings"],
  "require": [
    "ts-node/register",
    "tsconfig-paths/register",
    "tests/configs/mocha/setup.ts",
    "tests/configs/mocha/teardown.ts",
    "jsdom-global/register"
  ],
  "slow": 5000,
  "timeout": 60000
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["app", "./tests/**/*.ts", ".storybook/*.ts", ".storybook/*.tsx", "./playwright.config.ts", "*.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

